# Submiting a php form?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello guys i am grabing results from my mysql db and have made a html form and have put a submit button in side the php to submit the form.

```
<form method="post" action="buydo.php">
                <label><br />
                <br />
                </label>
                <p>


                <?php   
    $sql = "SELECT pokemon_name, Pokemon_pic, Pokemon_level, price FROM sell
             ORDER BY Pokemon_level ASC";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

        while ($v = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
            echo '
                <div class="auction_box">
                <img src="http://pokemontoxic.net/new_rpg/'.$v['Pokemon_pic'].'" width="100" height="100"><br/>
                &pound;'.$v['price'].'<br/>
                <label id="pokemonName'.$v['id'].'">'.$v['pokemon_name'].'</label><br/>

                <label>Level '.$v['Pokemon_level'].'</level><br/>
                <label>Time Left:';

                echo '</label>
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" id="'.$v['id'].'" class="buy_submit" value="Buy Now" /> </div>';
        }

?>



                &nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
              </form>
```

Im printing of all the $_posts on buydo.php but im getting nothing all i wanna do is get the $v['id'] from this script to the buydo page.  but for some resson ent going to the next page.  Ive got the connect and session start it shows the results and everything just when i press the submit button the info is not being submited im taking to buydo.php but nothing being posted ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a hidden input just above the submit input (it can go anywhere really, but having it there improves readability). Set the name to something static - for example, "pokemonID" - and set the value attribute to whatever you want to send to the next page. In this case, it would be $v['id']. Something similar to this would work:

```
<input type="hidden" name="pokemonID" value="' . $v['id'] . '" />
```

On the php page, you would use $_POST['pokemonID'] to access the data.

Comment: When i do echo $_POST['pokemonID']   i get nothing ??

Comment: Don't worry my own fault i ent getting the id from the sql select fixed it now will mark this has correct when it lets me thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correct you do load the `buydo.php` page but you don't get the value submitted so that you can access it using `$_POST`?

That's because you don't  have any input-elements in your form. Adding a hidden field would do the trick:

```
<input type="hidden" name="vid" value="'.$v['id'].'">
```

Now you can use the `$_POST['vid']` on `buydo.php` to access the value.

Answer (score 1):

The `id` attribute does not generally get posted, its main use is within the same HTML as an identifier.

What gets submitted via POST (or GET) are the name and value fields:

For example: `<input name='inputname' value='inputvalue' />` would make the submission target page get a $_POST['inputname']='inputvalue'

You can always use a hidden field: 
`<input type='hidden' name='id'.<unique_identifier_for_this_result> value=$v['id'] />`

and have a corresponding post

`<input type='submit' name='submit'.<the_same_unique_identifier_for_this_result> value='Buy' />`

The receiving page should then have received all hidden fields in the form and only the submit field you have selected. I.E. if you clicked on 'submit22' (identifier=22) then the $_POST['submit22'] would be set and actual hidden field you are interested in would be $_POST['id22']

An alternative method is to split each result in a separate form:

```
$sql = "SELECT pokemon_name, Pokemon_pic, Pokemon_level, price FROM sell
         ORDER BY Pokemon_level ASC";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    while ($v = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
        echo '<form method="post" action="buydo.php">
              ...
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value='.$v['id'].'
              <input type="submit" name="SubmB" value="Buy">
              </form>'
```